# Splitting a string within a dataframe and putting components on duplicated rows

Tags: python, split

I have a dataset containing slashes in multiple columns to seperate values. I would like to split these values at the slash and put onto new lines, whilst duplicating all other values. I would like to achieve `df_after`  from `df_before`, but in my case I have a more rows like this in the dataset.

```
df_before = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,2], 'B' : ['hey','hello/world','you'],
                          'C' : ['a','f','h'], 'D':['north','east/south','west']})

df_after = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,1,2],'B': ['hey','hello','world','you'],
                         'C':['a','f','f','h'],'D':['north','east','south','west']})
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(col):
    res = []
    for word in col:
        if isinstance(word, list):
            for sub_word in word[0].split('/'):
                res.append(sub_word)
        else:
            res.append(word)
    return res
df_before.apply(f)
```